Swap E T H For Exact Tokens >>what means is it?
please help me
I do it and do not understand its means.
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb2fde6b53411f0fc9cb69b952463be6525d8d5deaf733c8f32383b06d49bc199
From:
0x927319EbC401A47E7852848160AaED7AAC1EdD86
To:
0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506 (SushiSwap: Router)
Transfer
0.50511125175867936 BNB
From
SushiSwap: Router
To
BNB Chain: WBNB Token
BEP-20 Tokens Transferred: 2
All Transfers
Net Transfers
From
SushiSwap: Router
To
0xc7632B7b...d1439ec21
For
0.50511125175867936
$307.29
Wrapped BNB
(WBNB)
From
0xc7632B7b...d1439ec21
To
0x5e78F7B4...2127FeA19
For
300.2586702904319254
$300.29
Binance-Peg ...
(USDC)
Value:
BNB Smart Chain Logo
0.50511125175867936 BNB
($307.27)


First fund the router with eth so that it can be wrapped to WETH (pools don't support ETH (BNB/Native coin)

From: 0x927319EbC401A47E7852848160AaED7AAC1EdD86 
To: 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506 (SushiSwap: Router)


Wrap the ETH to WETH (BNB -> WBNB)
Then transfer it to the pool

Transfer 0.50511125175867936 BNB 
From SushiSwap: Router 
To BNB Chain: WBNB Token BEP-20 Tokens Transferred: 2 All Transfers Net Transfers 
From SushiSwap: Router 
To 0xc7632B7b...d1439ec21 For 0.50511125175867936 $307.29


Transfer USDC from pool to destination.

Wrapped BNB (WBNB) 
From 0xc7632B7b...d1439ec21 
To 0x5e78F7B4...2127FeA19 For 300.2586702904319254 $300.29
Binance-Peg ... (USDC) Value: BNB Smart Chain Logo 0.50511125175867936 BNB ($307.27)

USDC is here:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x5e78f7b4d41a7c5943e08ccbc9408422127fea19

Which is not the msg.sender address, but was input as the destination.
#   Name    Type    Data
0   amountOut   uint256 
 - 300258670290431925400
1   path    address[]   
 - 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c 
 - 0x8AC76a51cc950d9822D68b83fE1Ad97B32Cd580d

2   to  address 
 - 0x5e78F7B4d41A7C5943E08ccBc9408422127FeA19
3   deadline    uint256 
 - 1804853788

If interacting programmatically, directly through a block explorer or if using the advanced settings on the UI you can select a destination.
